# How to make an indexed word reference another indexed word in LyX?

Tags: lyx, indexing

The [LyX-Wiki](http://wiki.lyx.org/Tips/Indexing) tells me that it is possible for an index to reference an other one. A possible output could be

```
Index

B
Bar, see Foo

F
Foo, 9
```

which is invoked by `Bar|see{Foo}`, so the wiki states. But this simply does not work for me. Just to make sure I didn't miss anything:

1. I hit INSERT then selected INDEX near the word *Foo*.
2. Then I typed *Foo* into the small "area".
3. I did the same with *Bar* but here I typed `Bar|see{Foo}` into that area.

The result I get is

```
Index

F
Foo
```

*Bar* is completely missing in the index.

What do I miss?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A small piece of information is missing from the wiki, but can be found in the User guide (Help --> User guide, in LyX), section 6.6.3:

> It is also possible to refer to another index entry. We referred for
>   example in the index entry “GIF” (in section [sub:Image-Formats]) to
>   the index entry “Image formats” in the same section using the entry
>
> ```
> GIF|see{Image formats}
> ```
>
> **where the braces have to be inserted as TeX Code**. The text within the
>   braces is the referenced entry. The reference will appear in the
>   output without a page number.

Emphasis mine.

In other words, in `bar|see{foo}` put `{foo}`, or just the braces in `{foo}`,  in an ERT, e.g. by selecting it and hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>.

Comment: Is it possible to cross reference a grouped index entry?  For example, `GIF|see{File types ! Image formats}`.  I can't seem to manage it through various attempts, yet I can make `GIF|see{File types}` work.

Comment: @JFlo I don't really know how it's supposed to look, but that seems to work fine here.

Comment: what version are you using and what render format?  For me with Lyx v2.3.2 and PDF, my first example never does not appear in the index at all.

Comment: @JFlo 2.3.1, output to PDF with pdflatex. Here's an example LyX file: https://gist.github.com/TorbjornT/601a6092e83bfc7468c7a6723c2b883b

Comment: Ok, but what I am trying to accomplish is this: https://gist.github.com/jflorian/15a8871eeca481f48442d83a2c46299c. Note the bang in the cross-ref.

Comment: @JFlo Sorry, I think I made a mistake when copy-pasting, I'm pretty sure I tried what you wanted. Anyway, I'll have a look at your file, but I won't be able to do it until sunday evening at the earliest.

Comment: No hurry and not really that big of a deal, but it smells like an oversight that maybe I should report. Thanks!