# LyX index cross-referencing, "see" option

Tags: lyx, indexing

Exactly the same as [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50272/). I have tried the answer there, but I can't seem to get it to work even with various permutations.

I want to have an index entry that says "circular functions, *see* trigonometric functions". Here are what I've tried:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Each of the above produces the following index on page 3 of the output PDF, with the desired entry missing:

[image]

---

But if I use ERT:

[image]

Then I do get the desired output:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong or is this a possible LyX bug?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. I don't have a solution entirely using LyX, but I find that if I export to LaTeX (File -> Export -> LaTeX (pdflatex)) and run latex; makeidx, the missing entries magically appear.